# IndexError: list index out of range from my API to storage function?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a problem with my loop. I'm trying to pull data from an API for multiple stocks. While doing so, removing two columns of data that is returned in JSON, these columns are called `['label']` and `['currency']`. Please see my code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
previousday = {}

for x in tickers:
    r = requests.get(f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{x}/chart/date/20201028?chartByDay=true&token={IEX_SANDBOX_TOKEN}")
    try:
        data = r.json()
        if data[0]['label'] in data:
            del data[0]['label']
        elif data[0]['currency'] in data:
            del data[0]['currency']
            df = pd.json_normalize(data)
            df['symbol'] = x
            move_column_inplace(df,'symbol', 0)
            df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['symbol'])
            previousday[x] = df
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Response content is not valid: {x}")
```

This is the first time this issue is happening to me, I've used similar functions to pull data in a loop like above. But this new one I made is throwing something off. I've even tried removing those columns in pandas, instead of JSON but still getting the same `IndexError: list index out of range`.

The problem isn't from the API, when I call each ticker individually I get the data I'm expected to see. However not when I put it in this loop! I've tried multiple attempts to fix this but still haven't solved it. Thank you for any support.

EDIT: Full callback error bellow:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-216-c702a11783a3> in <module>
      5     r = requests.get(f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{x}/chart/date/20201028?chartByDay=true&token={IEX_SANDBOX_TOKEN}")
      6     data = r.json()
----> 7     if data[0]['label'] in data:
      8         del data[0]['label']
      9     elif data[0]['currency'] in data:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have if statements because I was checking if some stocks from the API was missing the columns I was trying to delete.

and incase you're curious, here is the error when I try to delete the columns in pandas =  `df.drop(['currency','label'], axis=1)`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-3c871a08bf8c> in <module>
      7     df = pd.json_normalize(data)
      8     df['symbol'] = x
----> 9     df.drop(['currency','label'], axis=1)
     10     move_column_inplace(df,'symbol', 0)
     11     #df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['symbol'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3995             level=level,
   3996             inplace=inplace,
-> 3997             errors=errors,
   3998         )
   3999 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3934         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3935             if labels is not None:
-> 3936                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3937 
   3938         if inplace:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3968                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   3969             else:
-> 3970                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   3971             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3972 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5015         if mask.any():
   5016             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5017                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   5018             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5019         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['currency' 'label'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: You're making us guess _where_ the error happens.  Please update the question to include the entire error traceback message.

Comment: Did you assert that the json list actually has data? Also these lines like `data[0]['label'] in data` seem wrong. You probably want `len(data) > 0 and 'label' in data[0]`

Comment: @flakes, inside my list is a dictionary of JSON data. The code looks looks funky but it's one way of selecting the fields which I want gone.

Comment: @JohnGordon, please see updated post. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: There is no ambiguity there. If you eat an out of range error with index 0, python is basically telling you that data is empty. Check the content of the variable r

Comment: `r` = is the response code from the API.